# No answer exists, but the site says 1 answer is there!

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, user-accounts, users

I asked a question sometime back, and then I saw someone answered it. But, when I try to open the page, all it says is 1 answer and there is nothing else there. There is no content, no-nothing!

Here it is: [Improving first person camera and implementing third person camera](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8126/improving-first-person-camera-and-implementing-third-person-camera)

Out of curiosity, I checked out who posted that reply and it turned out to be a bot "Community". I saw a similar pattern of having more number of answers, than the actual answers on other questions too. It was the same bot.

Can someone please explain if this is intentional or what ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleted answers.  Deleted user, hence the Community bot ownership.  Front page didn't update answer count, unfortunately.

Comment: the answer is a bit different in this case, as the underlying *user* was deleted. When answers are self-deleted by the user this will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

In places this may happen, counts are synced up appropriately now.  If they can't be (rare edge case), they are synced up once a day (around 3 AM UTC)...just to be sure.